# Greasemonkey script timeout option

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

In our company, we are using the firefox greasemonkey addon to fill in login credentials on a webpage to open it and login automatically.

This is what the script looks like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        logon
// @namespace   https://www.example.com
// @include     https://www.example.com
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript== 
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('input[name=username]').val('*****');
$('input[name=passcode]').val('*****');
$('input[name=send]').click(); 
});
```

Since upgrading to Firefox version 70, the script does not enter the login credentials anymore. 
I am under the impression that this is due to the page loading to slowly and the script executing to fast.

I would therefore like to insert a timeout in this script. So that it will only execute after 5 seconds after opening the page.

I have tried several examples found online, but none seems to work.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you demonstrate what example did you try and how it did not work? It might be more useful for you to know what mistake did you do, and not just get a code sample. Also keeping passwords in text file is big bad.

Answer (score 2):

If your *theory* about why it does not work is correct, the code below should work. Observe some other changes such as:

- JQuery is not needed for trivial things like this. Or any things. Just don't. It adds a dependency on your code for little benefit.
- You should **not** store password in plaintext script, but if you do at least put it in variable so that it's obvious to non-programmers where to change it.
- Using `someinput.form.submit()` also submits the form, and removes one input on which existence you have to rely on (the script still works if the submit button is renamed).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        logon
// @namespace   https://www.example.com
// @include     https://www.example.com
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @rut-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript== 

const TIMEOUT = 2000;
const NAME = "***";
const PASSWORD = "***";
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("input[name=username]").value = NAME;
        document.querySelector("input[name=passcode]").value = PASSWORD;
        document.querySelector("input[name=passcode]").form.submit();
    }, TIMEOUT);
});
```

But your original script may also have broken to other things than what you think, such as:

- Input fields renamed. Use dev tools to inspect them and see if there's any name, class name or ID.
- Framework is now used that does not read the values from fields, but only updates it's internal values when you type in them

Look in dev console to errors. Next time when asking, also demonstrate what have you tried and how it failed, otherwise you will not learn as much as you could have.